# On Labeling the cube

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory

Regularly in a Hamming hypercube, the vertices are labelled so that edge difference equals path difference. That is greater the edge difference, greater the hamming distance of the labelled vertices will be.

Can we label the cube so that lower the edge difference, higher will the Hamming distance be? Not all pairs of words will satisfy this property (for instance try labeling the 2-cube). However, is there a lower bound on how many close vertices any vertex can have and still have the property? Any references for this would help. This does sound like anticodes. However I am unsure.

Comment: do you have a motivation for this question? is it somehow related to metric-embeddings?